# Visual studio 2019 нету в отладчиках

Tags: visual-studio, отладка, visual-studio-2019

При вызове в коде `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()` Visual studio 2019 нету в меню выбора отладчиков.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что нужно сделать, что бы появилась? Не может это быть связано с тем, что код собран в старой студии или под старый фреймворк?

Comment: Я отменил конкурс, потому что мне показалось, что в данной ситуации это правильное решение. Если у других участников есть возражения, либо кто-то собирался написать подробный ответ про установку отладчика, ответьте на этот комментарий.

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Эх...

Оказывается JIT-отладчик отдельно нужно установить на Visual Studio 2019.
Поставил и все заработало.

А что бы его поставить, я просто вбил в поиске Visual Studio слова `Just-In-Time` и меня результат поиска переадресовал в программу установки доп. компонентов прямо на страницу jit-отлдачика, где я его собственно и поставил.

Comment: Вообще-то стоило бы поподробнее написать, что именно и как надо поставить.

Comment: @Qwertiy подпилил ответ малость.

Comment: Тогда ещё ссылку на страницу добавь.

Comment: Так там Visual Studio Installer открывается и ставит сам все.